# SADES SA-806 on xbox one

Tags: xbox-one

Bought this headset, wont work can only hear people talk in parties, no place to put the mic (red) cord, wondering if the split adapter for both of these plug ins will work on xbox one.

Answer (score 2):

I use a headset very similar to this for my Xbox One.  It has separate 3.5mm male connectors for mic and stereo audio out.

If your XB1 controller doesn't have a 3.5 mm jack on it, you'll need a [Xbox One Stereo Headset Adapter](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/headsets/stereo-headset-adapter).  It sounds like you're already plugging your headset into your controller, though.  That means you've either got a second-gen XB1 controller that has the jack, or you're using the adapter already.

The other piece you'll need is a 3.5mm headset adapter, one that goes from two, 3-position 3.5mm female in to one, 4-position 3.5mm male out.  It sounds complicated, but it's really quite simple.  Just plug in the two cords from your headset to one end, and then put the single male jack into the controller.

[Here's one device](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Adapter-Male-to-Female~MUYHSMFF) that will likely work, but there are tons available on Newegg, Amazon, etc.